# tool to make all styles inline?

Tags: css, inline, html-email, craigslist

"good lord, man, why would you want to do that? don't you know that inline styles are EVIL?!"

ya, I know.

but i want to make real html emails, and real pretty craigslist ads [1], and as you know, they (mostly) only support inline styles. i'd like to have pretty, manageable, css themes for them, but obviously, this is impractical with inline styles.

so, what i'm looking for is a tool (php or jquery pref), that can take all the styles that apply to a document or block of text, and output some new html, but with the styles inline. know of one?

thanks in advance!

[1] i know what you're thinking, CL doesn't support css, but that's not actually true. some sections let u put in css.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tools to automatically inline CSS style to create email HTML code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Question has an answer with a JQuery implementation of what you want.
[Copying CSS to inline using jquery (or retaining formatting when copying stuff from a web page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307409/copying-css-to-inline-using-jquery-or-retaining-formatting-when-copying-stuff-fr)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this converter, might help:
http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com