# CSS table formatting lost on copy paste IE to Outlook email

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am in the process of updating an internal company website.
On the website is a table of summary data. Each day this table is copied from the page into an email and sent to people using Outlook 2010. The company currently is using IE8.

The problem is that the new website is using Twitter Bootstrap for the table styling. When copying and pasting the table into Outlook, most of the styling is missing.

The old website has classes attached to each `tr`, `td`, etc.

Chrome works without any issues on the new website.

Here are some examples of the table and problem:

Old site - http://jsbin.com/ifeqav/1/edit

New site - http://jsbin.com/iwuven/1/edit

Does anyone know of a fix for this? I have tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4307826/1873505) but it doesn't appear to work correctly with bootstrap.

Does IE9 fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook 2007 and later do not use IE for HTML message formatting. Instead they use Word's (yes, it's terrible, everyone knows). Word does not support many features in CSS2, let alone CSS3. This unfortunately means the best way to serve graphical emails to Outlook users is to send them 1990s-era HTML emails: the horror of `<table>` for layout and the return of the evil `spacer.gif`. This abhorrent practice is acceptable because Outlook/Word does not interpret any semantic content.

Or just include a link at the top of your emails that say: "Using Outlook? Click here to view your message in your browser".

Comment: Well that is disappointing. Sounds like the only solution is to have them change the process that they do now with how the emails are created.