# CSS classes to style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to do html table to excel file, i find a javascript code for it and its working great but my site has classes for elements. I want that classes attributes to style attribute with jquery function or something.

Example

css

```
.myTable
{
   background : black; color:white;
}
```

html

```
<table class="myTable"></table>
```

that is is i want ;

```
<table style="background : black; color:white;"></table>
```

when i do this, my excel file will be formated like in my site. there is any way to do this ?

Comment: what about find and replace ??

Comment: I think you are looking for this stuff . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307409/copying-css-to-inline-using-jquery-or-retaining-formatting-when-copying-stuff-f

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/E57Xu/ Do you looking for this .

Comment: @rahularyansharma its the answer, but i can't mark as answer. write it with post for mark :P

Comment: @user2107255 Thanks i am writing this in answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this here just becuase OP wants it here . I have taken this solution from another [so answer which can be find  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307409/copying-css-to-inline-using-jquery-or-retaining-formatting-when-copying-stuff-f) .

```
  (function($) {
        $.extend($.fn, {
            makeCssInline: function() {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var style = el.style;
                    var properties = [];
                    for(var property in style) { 
                        if($(this).css(property)) {
                            properties.push(property + ':' + $(this).css(property));
                        }
                    }
                    this.style.cssText = properties.join(';');
                    $(this).children().makeCssInline();
                });
            }
        });
    }(jQuery));


    $('.myTable').makeCssInline();
```

[MY JS FIDDLE LINK can also be find here](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/E57Xu/)

Answer (score 4):

So you should rewrite **all** styles(inline, external, etc) associated with element to it's "style" attribute.

Under following link, there is a solution how to do that:
[Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Comment: After three answers i think you only the person who read the question correctly. This is another answer on SO which is  almost same to current one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307409/copying-css-to-inline-using-jquery-or-retaining-formatting-when-copying-stuff-f Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery css method to apply

```
$('table').css({background:black,color:white}); //this will apply for all tables
```

or  you can add that class also to the table via addClass()

`$('table').addClass('myTable');` //this will apply for all tables

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css selector to style all tables:

```
table
{
   background : black; color:white;
}
```